# Pybind11 pickle a c++ instance with dynamically allocated attributes

Tags: c++, serialization, heap-memory, pickle, pybind11

Suppose I have a simple class like this:

`Entity.h`

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

class Entity {
public:
    int *field;
    Entity(const py::list& data);
    ~Entity();
}
```

`Entity.cpp`

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(const py::list& data) {
    field = new int[py::len(data)];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) field[i] = py::int_(data[i]);
}

~Entity::Entity() { delete[] field; }
```

Now I bind it to Python with `pybind11` like this:

`Bind.cpp`

```
#include "Entity.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(Entity, module) {
    py::class_<Entity>(module, "Entity")
        .def(py::init<const py::list&>())
        .def(py::pickle(
            // Here I have no clue what to write
        ));
}
```

[Pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#pickling-support) suggests that the `__getstate__` method be defined with `py::make_tuple` which should make a tuple with all the values of the attributes. The thing is, the value is a pointer, and all the data on the heap is deleted upon termination of the program.

How can I serialize an object with dynamically allocated attributes using pybind11?

Comment: Isn't the question concrete enough? Any suggestions?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @erentknn yes, I just added a method for serialization which dumped everything via `fstream` by invoking byte writing and reading functions and made that method visible on the python side. The serialization code in my project looks like [this](https://github.com/Kaiyakha/NeuralAnalysisOfImageNoise-CppBased/blob/master/NeuralNetwork/Serialize.cpp). The most obvious solution when there are no tools to come in handy is to make one on your own, so that's what I did, not in the safest way probably, but still